# Discontinued ads exchange of 125px square?

Tags: advertising, banners

From more than 4 years ago [AdBrite](http://www.adbrite.com) was recommending its users to use a free banners exchange service characterized by its square 125px banners. That service was discontinued from about three years.

My question is: Is there anyone remember the name of this service. I just remember that its name was ended with three identical letters and its logo has a small dog drawing.

Someone may wonder why I ask about it! I just asking to easily search for an equivalent service like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Finally I remembered it. It was [Spottt.com](http://spottt.com). one of my friends told me that and remembered me with it. Checkout [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/VzFzJl5qVpg)

> **Edit**
>
> By the way the regarded domain, *spottt.com*, has A record points to the internal
>   loop IP `127.0.0.1`, so if you have a local web server on your machine
>   it will point to it.